# Dynamically add button disappears when anchored

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, anchor

I have a really simple Dynamically add button. It works fine, but when I set the anchor property it does not show anymore.

```
    Dim btn As New Button() With {.Text = "Cerrar", .Location = New Drawing.Point(8, 368)} 'Crea el boto
    Me.Controls.Add(btn)
    btn.BringToFront()
    btn.Show()

    btn.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Right
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.Dispose 'Tanca la Pestanya al clicar btn
```

If I comment the "btn.anchor..." line it shows and works. When debbuging it shows that the property is set fine.

What's happening?

---

As you have sugested, I added the button to the form after the handler and anchor, nothing changed.

I though that maybe the anchor is moving down my butto, so i tried to locate it at (1,1)... And the anchor seems to be moving it.

[Here it is without the anchor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2hXl.jpg) The button is the one outlined in red.

[Now without comenting the anchor set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAIYw.jpg) As you can see the button have been moved down and left.

The only change in the code is that im setting the anchor to bottom on the second one.

There is nothing starting there, it just seems an arbritary position.

Comment: What happens if you set the anchor and add the click handler before adding the control to the form?

Comment: Try setting the anchor before adding the button to the controls collection. And set the btn.Visible = True, not btn,Show()